# How to Run Apache Tika on Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-tika

I am trying to run Apache Tika on Apache Spark on AWS EMR to perform distributed text extraction on a large collection of documents. I have built the Tika JAR with shaded dependencies as explained in https://forums.databricks.com/questions/28378/trying-to-use-apache-tika-on-databricks.html and the job works correctly in local mode. However when running the job in clustered mode, the extracted text always comes out as an empty string. This problem is outlined in Tika's documentation (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-NoContentExtracted), but I haven't been able to debug the issue. Since the code works for me in local mode it has to be something with the classpath or JARs, and I can't figure it out.

Here is sample Scala code for my Spark job:

```
/* TikaTest.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.tika.parser._
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata
import java.io.DataInputStream

// The first argument must be an S3 path to a directory with documents for text extraction.
// The second argument must be an S3 path to a directory where extracted text will be written.
object TikaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Tika Test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val binRDD = sc.binaryFiles(args(0))
    val textRDD = binRDD.map(file => {parseFile(file._2.open( ))})
    textRDD.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
    sc.stop()
  }

  def parseFile(stream: DataInputStream): String = {
    val parser = new AutoDetectParser()
    val handler = new BodyContentHandler()
    val metadata = new Metadata()
    val context = new ParseContext()
 
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context)
    return handler.toString()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you including tika-parsers in Tika 1.x or tike-parsers-standard-package in 2.x?